# xml commenting for tag helper intellisense

Tags: asp.net-core, intellisense, tag-helpers

I am writing a tag helper and am having issues getting the XML comments to display via Intellisense in my Razor View.  I thought the code snippet below would work for the tag itself:

```
namespace WebApplication.TagHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// My Element
    /// </summary>
    public class MyTagHelper : TagHelper
```

I've also tried data annotation (and wasn't sure of the syntax):

```
[DisplayName("My Tag")]
public class MyTagHelper : TagHelper
```

But this also doesn't work.  I made certain to include the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools package in my project.json under both the dependencies and the tools. I also made certain that XML documentation was turned on inside of my Visual Studio enviroment. I tried looking for similar posts, but did not see any.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have green squigglies under your classes and methods where you DON'T have tags above?

Comment: No, If I remove the data annotation or the XML comments, it still compiles correctly.  However on my razor view page, it offers autocomplete for the tag, not a revised summary.   (it displays the full class name WebApplication.TagHelpers.My on hover, but nothing else).

Comment: Have you enabled xmldocs compilation in your project where the taghelper is defined?

Comment: That was it!  I missed that in my project settings.  Once I enabled it, the green squigglies showed up and comment was properly applied.   Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raising this from the comments so the question can be marked as answered:

Enable XML Docs generation when compiling to get `Summary` comments raised to work at dev time.

---

#### Extra Info

If you're a TagHelper author, packaging your project should generate the XML docs file.